# How can I access a fieldSet inside a custom button javascript

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, fieldsets

I am trying to use FieldSets in a custom button but getting this error:

> Field Lead.FieldSets.Submit_Fields does not exist. Check spelling.

How can I access a fieldSet inside a **Custom Button** javascript?
This is what I am trying to do:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")}

function insertScript(title, body, draggable){ 

        var box = new SimpleDialog("hersh"+Math.random(), draggable); 
          parent.box = box; 
          box.setTitle(title); 
          box.createDialog(); 
          box.setWidth(350); 
          box.setContentInnerHTML(body); 
          box.setupDefaultButtons(); 
          box.show();
}

var body = '<apex:page standardController="Lead"> <apex:form><apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Lead.FieldSets.Submit_Fields}" var="f"><apex:inputField label="{!f.Label}" required="{!f.Required}" value="!Lead[f.fieldPath]}"/><br/></apex:repeat></apex:form></apex:page>';

insertScript("Submit",body,true);
```

Comment: Why don't you just create that `Visualforce Page` in reality and then use an `iframe`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson because I am not sure how to do it. Can you explain?